# Outlook 2010: Is it possible to multi-select different emails across multiple folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, selection

Normally, you can CTRL+right click to select multiple emails in a folder.  You can then forward all emails at once and they will appear as attachments in the email you're composing.

I happen to have several emails that span multiple folders that I'd like to multi-select for that purpose, but it doesn't appear that there's any native functionality to allow me to preserve selections across folders.  As soon as you switch folders, your selections from the previous folder are gone.

**Update:** I've just discovered a trick in my haste to find a solution here.  I start a new message and then drag and drop emails into it.  So I'll select multiple emails from one folder and drag them into the new email then I'll select multiple emails from another folder and drag and drop them into the new email.  This achieves the net result I am looking for, but I am hoping to still be able to select multiple emails across different folders.

Comment: You found the best option for this. Alternative is within the email to use "attach item" > "outlook item", but this only achieves the same thing a different way, and still only one folder at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered a trick in my haste to find a solution here. I start a new message and then drag and drop emails into it. So I'll select multiple emails from one folder and drag them into the new email then I'll select multiple emails from another folder and drag and drop them into the new email. This achieves the net result I am looking for, but I am hoping to still be able to select multiple emails across different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Possible option: use a search to find the emails you want. You can select search results which are returned from multiple folders this way. Likewise with a saved search.

Also note if you use conversation view, you can select several emails from different folders in one or more conversations and "forward" these all together.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I can see this method as being sort of tedious.  Using the search feature implies that you know everything you need to know about each message you're looking for (eg, subject, recipients, etc).  Most of the time, my memory is only refreshed after I scroll through a folder and come upon the messages I am looking for.  Also, not all messages will necessarily be part of the same thread.  The only all-inclusive method I can find is the one I pointed out as an update in my question.